# Deploying CAR files like RPM

Tags: wso2, rpm, wso2-esb

I am working with WSO2 ESB and I would like to build my .car project like RPM to deploy on Redhat servers.

I have several .car project and I have to manage dependencies between them. I have thought that it is a good idea to do it.

Has anybody tired this before? Where can I find more information about this? Should I use hot-deploys putting .car file into /repository/deployment/server/carbonapps directory?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use hot deploy putting .car files into carbonapps, but take care of downloading them on the ESB local filesystem before moving them to carbonapps so that the ESB don't start deploying them before the end of the download.

You can develop your own script and rely on a config file defining dependencies so that your numerous .car are deployed in the right order

You can use maven and plugin org.wso2.maven:maven-car-plugin that offers you a way to package and deploy your .car from a remote host with something like mvn clean deploy -Dhost=esbhostname -Dport=9443

Hope it gives you some ideas to achieve your need...

Comment: Thanks for your help. That is more or less I have thougth it, but I do not dawn on download .car in filesystem before moving to carbonapps.